# Build a predictive model with Python using SQL Server 2017 Machine Learning Services

Tags: python, sql-server, machine-learning, prediction

I'm following this tutorial and I'm getting the expected answer succesfully.

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/machine-learning-services/python/getting-started/rental-prediction

My question is, given the current data, how do I predict future data. For example 'Rental Counts' for year 2016 in this case.

Dataset:

[image]

PYTHON CODE (Complete Script)

```
    import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#If you are running SQL Server 2017 RC1 and above:
from revoscalepy import RxComputeContext, RxInSqlServer, RxSqlServerData
from revoscalepy import rx_import

def get_rental_predictions():
#Connection string to connect to SQL Server named instance
 conn_str = 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=SQLSERVER;Database=TutorialDB;Trusted_Connection=True;'

#Define the columns we wish to import
column_info = {
         "Year" : { "type" : "integer" },
         "Month" : { "type" : "integer" },
         "Day" : { "type" : "integer" },
         "RentalCount" : { "type" : "integer" },
         "WeekDay" : {
             "type" : "factor",
             "levels" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
         },
         "Holiday" : {
             "type" : "factor",
             "levels" : ["1", "0"]
         },
         "Snow" : {
             "type" : "factor",
             "levels" : ["1", "0"]
         }
     }

 #Get the data from SQL Server Table
data_source = RxSqlServerData(table="dbo.rental_data", connection_string=conn_str, column_info=column_info)
computeContext = RxInSqlServer(
     connection_string = conn_str,
     num_tasks = 1,
     auto_cleanup = False
)


RxInSqlServer(connection_string=conn_str, num_tasks=1, auto_cleanup=False)

 # import data source and convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rx_import(input_data = data_source))
print("Data frame:", df)
 # Get all the columns from the dataframe.
columns = df.columns.tolist()
 # Filter the columns to remove ones we don't want to use in the training
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ["Year"]]
  # Store the variable we'll be predicting on.
target = "RentalCount"
 # Generate the training set.  Set random_state to be able to replicate results.
train = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)
 # Select anything not in the training set and put it in the testing set.
test = df.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]
 # Print the shapes of both sets.
print("Training set shape:", train.shape)
print("Testing set shape:", test.shape)
 # Initialize the model class.
lin_model = LinearRegression()
 # Fit the model to the training data.
lin_model.fit(train[columns], train[target])

 # Generate our predictions for the test set.
lin_predictions = lin_model.predict(test[columns])
print("Predictions:", lin_predictions)
 # Compute error between our test predictions and the actual values.
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(lin_predictions, test[target])
print("Computed error:", lin_mse)

get_rental_predictions()
```

SQL Stored Procedure. Only the portion that generates prediction from test data

```
------------------ STEP 4  - Use the model to predict number of rentals --------------------------
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS py_predict_rentalcount;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE py_predict_rentalcount (@model varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @py_model varbinary(max) = (select model from rental_py_models where model_name = @model);

    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
                    @language = N'Python'
                  , @script = N'


import pickle
rental_model = pickle.loads(py_model)


df = rental_score_data
#print(df)

# Get all the columns from the dataframe.
columns = df.columns.tolist()
# Filter the columns to remove ones we dont want.
# columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ["Year"]]

# Store the variable well be predicting on.
target = "RentalCount"

# Generate our predictions for the test set.
lin_predictions = rental_model.predict(df[columns])
print(lin_predictions)

# Import the scikit-learn function to compute error.
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# Compute error between our test predictions and the actual values.
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(lin_predictions, df[target])
#print(lin_mse)

import pandas as pd
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(lin_predictions)
OutputDataSet = pd.concat([predictions_df, df["RentalCount"], df["Month"], df["Day"], df["WeekDay"], df["Snow"], df["Holiday"], df["Year"]], axis=1)
'
    , @input_data_1 = N'Select "RentalCount", "Year" ,"Month", "Day", "WeekDay", "Snow", "Holiday"  from rental_data where Year = 2015'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'rental_score_data'
    , @params = N'@py_model varbinary(max)'
    , @py_model = @py_model
    with result sets (("RentalCount_Predicted" float, "RentalCount" float, "Month" float,"Day" float,"WeekDay" float,"Snow" float,"Holiday" float, "Year" float));

END;
GO
```

Comment: Hector, we need more information. Like what have you tried, outside of copy/pasting this tutorial and what exactly is not working? For the best results in this situation, we need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you're tutorial is working, and you're question only deals with extending the example to predict on 2016 data, instead of 2015 data, then the core of your problem is in your python/sklearn code. Edit the question, remove all of the sql, and try to be specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Austin. Reading the mcve guidelines it seems it'd be hard to provide a portion of the code that can reproduce the issue since it is the combination of all components that produce the result hence added the entire script. SQL is part of the title of the question but I'll edit the question and attempt to add the python code only. The solution is built as a copy/paste with the assumption the user understands tsql and db structure. Everything is working, the question is what should the code be to predict outside of the already recorded dates.

Comment: If that is your question, then the sql is unnecessary. Sure, you're using it to execute the python script, but the python script is where training and prediction take place. In order to guide you about how to train and predict on your data, I would suggest simplifying this question. Let's first look at your data, understand what features and labels you want to train on and go from there. Extract the data from the db as a csv and let's only deal with the python script. Once you understand how that works, I believe incorporating that into the example is a simple process.